# How can I construct a tree using d3 and its force layout?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to arrange my nodes in the form of a tree. For now, I am working off of this example from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xReHA/2/). Currently, I am relying on a force directed layout but am trying to modify it such that I can obtain a tree with predetermined number of levels i.e. if a node belongs to a particular "Layer" it should belong to the same area as other nodes in the layer.

I have tried to explain more in the picture below but does anyone have any suggestions for this? Are there any predetermined algorithms inside `d3` that do this or can be tweaked to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: The source contains an example for a dynamic tree. You should have a look at it, it might be what you want (at least it looks similar). *edit:* I mean [this example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/tree/tree-dynamic.html).

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a force-directed layout here instead of a static tree layout, e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/1061834 ?

Comment: @nrabinowitz: +1 Thank you. Can't believe I missed it! I guess both will serve my purpose! Is there a way I can make them interactive so that the nodes just come back when I drag them somewhere? This helps drag some node and explain it to someone.

Comment: @FelixKling: +1 Thank You. I had one additional question that I wrote above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your diagram looks nearly identical to [this example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20110921/depth-foci.html) which uses a custom gravity force based on the depth. There's [another example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20110921/parent-foci.html) using a custom force which attracts to the parent node. These are both from [my talk](http://vimeo.com/29458354) on force layouts.

Of course, force layouts are only one option—and as @nrabinowitz said there are many more [hierarchy layouts](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Layouts). You can find [more](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/pack.html) [interactive](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) [hierarchy](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html) [examples](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/cluster.html) in my SVG Open talk.

Comment: You're really a legend! Thank you very much for taking the time to show me all the examples. And by the way, very informative talk.

Comment: These links are all broken

Comment: @mbostock please repost the missing examples. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @mbostock can you please repost links, seems they are broken, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The examples that mbostock referred to are here: https://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/#20
You can inspect the HTML to see the Javascript code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).